# Update the model objects after changing one of them

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
class BroadcastingTable(models.Model):
    tv_programm = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=tv_programm_list)
    brd_date = models.DateField()
    brd_start = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    brd_stop = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    brd_duration = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    brd_duration_day = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    brd_duration_mounth = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

my forms.py:

```
class TableChoiseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BroadcastingTable
```

and views:

```
def index(request):
    broadcastingtable = BroadcastingTable.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'BroadcastingJournal/broadcastingPage.html', 
locals(),)

def edit(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(BroadcastingTable, id=pk)
    edit_form = TableChoiseForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    try:
        if edit_form.is_valid():
            instance = edit_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
        else:
            edit_form = TableChoiseForm(instance=instance)
        return render(request, 'BroadcastingTableChoise/choisePage.html', 
{"form": edit_form,})
    except BroadcastingTable.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("<h2>Запись не найдена</h2>")
```

In the form, the user enters **the date**, **the start_time** and **the end_time** every day, based on the start_time and end_time, the duration time for the month is calculated. Duration mounth time is the sum of the duration time of each day in a month. In **viwes.py** there is an **"edit"** function for changing data through a form. Sometimes it is necessary to change old entries for the previous days, but after changing one of the objects in the middle, there is no recalculation of the following objects and the broadcasting time for the month remains incorrect.How after changing the object to recalculate the duration month time for all next objects of the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can check [signals on a post save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save) of your object.

You check when an object is modified, get the objects that come after (if there's any) and re calculate the time for the month.